# How to increase maxDate in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two input boxes in the first input box user select date and in second input box the date that should come for selection must be 2 days from that selected day, here is the snippet of code

```js
$(function() {
  var checkIn = $("#date-1"); var checkOut = $("#date-2");
  var todayDate = new Date();

  checkIn.datepicker({
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth:true,
    changeYear:false,
    minDate:todayDate

  });
  
  checkIn.on("change",function() {
    var select = checkIn.datepicker("getDate") ;
    var  checkOutDate = select;
    checkOut.datepicker('option','minDate',checkOutDate);
    checkOut.datepicker('option','maxDate',"+2d");
  });
  
  checkOut.datepicker({
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth:false,
    changeYear:false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="date-1" placeholder="Date 1">
  <input type="text" id="date-2" placeholder="Date 2">
</form>
```

The problem is it **doesn't set the date when the month is changed** with some different date i have also tried this

```
 checkOut.datepicker('option','maxDate',checkOutDate);
```

But it doesn't work either i know i am missing some parameter but what is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `"+2d"` param calculates the diff from now, not from its current value. So in your example, you order to `datepicker` to show a range between the selected date and now + 2 days. So you get a negative gap => no range displayed. Here a solution :

```js
$(function() {
  const checkIn = $("#date-1");
  const checkOut = $("#date-2");
  const todayDate = new Date();

  checkIn.datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    minDate: todayDate,
  });
  
  checkOut.datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
  });
  
  checkIn.on("change", function() {
    const checkOutDate = checkIn.datepicker("getDate");
    const diffDate = checkOutDate - todayDate
    const fromNow = Math.ceil(diffDate / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    
    checkOut.datepicker("option", {
      minDate: fromNow,
      maxDate: fromNow + 2,
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
<form>
  <input type="text" id="date-1" placeholder="Date 1">
  <input type="text" id="date-2" placeholder="Date 2">
</form>
```